# What is the difference between work teams and TFS groups?

Tags: tfs

What is the difference between work teams and TFS groups?

because I see that they are the same privileges.

Comment: Did you start by reading the documentation on teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply say they have the same and different points.

**Same:**

- A group of people;
- Can manage security permission based on Team, or Group. Assign
  permission to team or group.

**Different**

- Team is used to reorganize team project, user can select to show data
  within team project, or a specified team. See [Configure team settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/work/scale/manage-team-assets) and [Add teams and team members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams) for details.
- Group mainly used to manage security for TFS users.

---

You can also reference below article to understand the teams and groups:

- [Understanding teams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528603(v=vs.110).aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-FHWrGpBDHrSbz0alu3PEAw&tduid=(eb1b3f9e1e2d544869190b8487199391)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-FHWrGpBDHrSbz0alu3PEAw)())
- [Team Foundation Server Security for Users and Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252512(v=vs.80).aspx)
- [Configure initial groups, teams, members, and permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/process-templates/configure-initial-groups-teams-members-permissions#define-a-team)
- [About permissions and groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/about-permissions)